# jssor slider add external link to the thumbnail

Tags: jssor

I am using the jssor templete for my slider and I have modified the setting so that I can have a slider image change when the mouse hover on the thumbnail. But I do not know how to add an external link to the thumbnail image so that I can go to the another page associated with that picture 
I have try the following method from http://quabr.com/28478806/jssor-external-links-on-thumbnails but it is not worked

```
<div>
    <img u="image" src="../img/photography/002.jpg" />
    <div u="thumb">
    <a href="http://mylink.com" target="_blank"><img class="i"   src="../img/photography/thumb-002.jpg"/></a>
    </div>
    <div u="caption" t="L">My Title</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: please post your thumbnail navigator skin code here.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it worked already.

But there is an extra enclosing '<div>' in following code,

```
<div>
    <img u="image" src="../img/photography/002.jpg" />
    <div u="thumb">
    <a href="http://mylink.com" target="_blank"><img class="i"   src="../img/photography/thumb-002.jpg"/></a>
    </div>
    <div u="caption" t="L">My Title</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please remove it by replacing

```
    <div u="caption" t="L">My Title</div>
    </div>
```

with

```
    <div u="caption" t="L">My Title</div>
```

Also, please set 'height: 100%' for 'a' element to make the clickable area bigger.

```
<a href="http://mylink.com" target="_blank" style="height: 100%;">
```

And finally, please check out the thumbnail navigator skin html code, because it is fully customizable, and it can be very complicated. Please make sure your link element is not covered by any other element.